# how can I share React jsx files bewteen MVC projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, visual-studio

I have 3 MVC projects 2 of them are websites while the third one ideally will be shared between the other 2. The goal of the third MVC project is to share ReactJS forms between the 2 sites since the forms will be identical. What is the best approach to share reactjs components between all the projects?

Thanks, Jordan

**EDIT**
The most common answer that I don't believe will work is adding the file as a link. Because this code is in TFS so I would have to update the TFS code every time I wanted to test. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Hi you could create factory components, build them and then be able to install them inside your _consuming_ project

Comment: could you find a link to what you are thinking? having troubles finding anything relevant.

Comment: Yep here's one: https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library

Comment: Yea were trying to avoid using Git, Nuget, or NPM, but because the already created site is an .NET FrameWork MVC project. Does a .NET Core MVC project and a .NET FrameWork project work together well?